# Input groups bigger than input in Bootstrap 3 using Jumbotron container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experimenting a strange behavior with Bootstrap 3 input groups. When I add an input-group-addon (text or icon) to a form inside a jumbotron, the input-group height is bigger than its input height.

Here you can find a JsFiddle and an screenshot with the problem:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Jumbotron with form</h1>
        <form>
           <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
           </div> 
        </form>
  </div>
```

Live example at http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Screenshot: [image]

How can I fix this problem? I'm looking for a Bootstrap solution but if that's not possible would be nice if you could help me to fix it with CSS rules.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The bootstrap solution is to add the `input-group-lg` class on the containing `<div>` - as [shown in the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), but you'll notice the addon is still slightly larger than the input so you can just adjust the height of the `<input>` to match; I added 5 px:

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/21/

Comment: It's still not quite right (couple px off in bootstrap 3.0.3). I hosang's solution of fixing the problem below is probably better

Comment: @TomDignan: I agree that is the better solution; I'll delete this answer if the OP unaccepts it.

Answer (score 37):

Last night, I had exactly the same problem. None of the fixes mentioned above worked in my context. What finally did do the job was setting the margin to 0:

```
.input-group .form-control {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Perhaps this helps someone with a similar problem!

Comment: Thanks for post it! Save my life :P Keep going on this :)

Comment: I don't know how did u find it but you are f--king awesome guy! thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, this too did not work for me - the size of the addon is still disproportionate. I ended up using [input-group-btn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21408657/1526703).

Answer (score 10):

The main problem of `.input-group-addon` size within `.jumbotron` is that it inherits **`font-size`** of `.jumbotron`.

Usually, people are trying to change height, min-height or padding etc.

**However** the cause of different size is that `.input-group` in `.jumbotron` inherits **`"font-size: 21px;"`**

You should change the `font-size` of `.input-group` **NOT** `.input-group-addon` like below.

```
.input-group { font-size: 14px !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Bootstrap's doc as Adrift suggests, your original code looks perfectly valid.  Adding the input-group-lg class is great if you want LARGE but if you don't, it's wrong. Using IE9 and running your code in both my own dev environment and Adrift's jsfiddle, it's working correctly (for me) with and without the input-group-lg class, except of course that with it it's rendered large.  Perhaps a browser specific issue??

That said, I'm experiencing a similar problem trying to add a radio button at the front of a selectpicker.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it be adding `id="search_button"` to my button:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="search_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">GO</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I then applied the following style to my button:

```
#search_button {
    width: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run across the same issue.

I fixed by modifying adrift's answer to :

```
<div class="input-group input-group-fix">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputlbl-field1">field1</span>
   </div>
   <input id="field1" type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="field1" aria-describedby="inputlbl-field1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">
</div>
```

And then adding the following CSS

```
.input-group-fix > .form-control, .input-group-fix > .input-group-addon, .input-group-fix > .input-group-btn > .btn {
    height: 43px;
}
```

This gives me greater control on where I want to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with bootstrap 4. 
Then I realized my css had following setup for span tags:

```
 span {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: #0c5460;
        }
```

Hence all my spans were big. 
Once I removed it, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the **form-control input** set to **font-size: 100%** - and that was causing this issue for me. Removed that CSS, and the issue went away. (Bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this css style on your header style tag.

```
.input-group {  font-size:0px !important  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**if someone is still looking for an answer**. This is what helped me.
So I tried to style the `.input-group-addon` class, but it was not doing anything, so I changed `.input-group` class instead and set the height to 20px (as i have my input fields set to 20px) and it worked **perfectly** for my case. (screenshot attached)

[image]

Hope it helps. Let me know if anyone needs a working jsfiddle example.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of making the input bigger, make the span (input-group-addon) smaller. To do that, make its padding lower. So:

```
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 0px 6px;
}
```