# Input group - two inputs close to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I make input group involves two inputs?

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal">
</div>
```

This doesn't work, they are horizontal instead of inline

Comment: My solution requires no additional css and works with any combination of input-addon, input-btn and form-control. It just uses pre-existing bootstrap classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/34208228/2273611

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming you want them next to each other:

```html
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal">   
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/1/)

**Update Nr.1:** Should you want to use `.input-group` with this example:

```html
<form action="" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/3/)

The class `.input-group` is there to extend inputs with buttons and such (directly attached). Checkboxes or radio buttons are possible as well. I don't think it works with two input fields though.

**Update Nr. 2:** With `.form-horizontal` the `.form-group` tag basically becomes a `.row` tag so you can use the column classes such as `.col-sm-8`:

```html
<form action="" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Updated JSFiddle with all three examples](http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/4/)

Comment: I want to use form-horizontal but in one line I need to have 2 inputs

Comment: @JohnSmith: If you're using form-horizontal, then you're using the grid system so you'll need the col- attributes as well. I've added a third example demonstrating this technique.

Comment: There is ```<div class="clearfix"></div>``` **missing** inside ```<div class="form-group">...</div>```

Comment: The problem with `form-horizontal` is that when the screen is smaller(and it is using the `xs` styles) the two inputs are on separate lines (which is good, if somebody wants to make it responsive), BUT there is no space between them. What would be the solution in this case?

Comment: Best answer without any additional CSS or modifications +1

Comment: @PiotrKowalczuk No clearfix is required, your `form-group` should be wrapped in `<form class='form-horizontal'></form>`

Answer (score 120):

working workaround:

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="test1" />
    <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="test2" />
</div>
```

downside: no border-collapse between the two text-fields, but they keep next to each other

http://jsfiddle.net/EfC26/

**Update**

thanks to [Stalinko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244262/stalinko)

This technique allows to glue more than 2 inputs. 
Border-collapsing is achieved using `"margin-left: -1px"` (`-2px` for the 3rd input and so on)

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="test1" />
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="test2" style="margin-left:-1px" />
  <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="test2" style="margin-left:-2px" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLvk5mn1/1/

Comment: How would you change the widths of these inputs? It's always 50/50.

Comment: Don't forget to specify paddings, because even with zero width element still has it.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. `input-group-btn` works for me better than `input-group-addon` since the size of the addon is somehow not proportionate with the size of the input box.

Comment: Adding `border-left: 0;` to the second input will collapse borders

Comment: I prefer styling the `border` of inputs rather than setting -ve margins. It's as simple as setting `border-right: 0;` to 1st input, `border-left: 0;` to last input and `border-left: 0; border-right: 0;` to all other inputs in `.input-group` (inspiration from @MbengueAssane comment). Otherwise, with -ve margins there will be noticeable difference in the total width of the `.form-group` with 3 or more inputs in `.input-group`

Answer (score 70):

It almost never makes intuitive sense to have two inputs next to each other without labels. Here is a solution with labels mixed in, which also works quite well with just a minor modification to existing Bootstrap styles.

**Preview:**
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Between</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something..." />
  <span class="input-group-addon" style="border-left: 0; border-right: 0;">and</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type something..." />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.input-group-addon {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
}
.input-group-addon:first-child {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.input-group-addon:last-child {
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yLvk5mn1/31/

Comment: "It almost never makes intuitive sense to have two inputs next to each other without labels." - my use case was specifying a "from year - until year" range. It was on a search page, so space was a big concern.

Comment: @user2524350 fair enough, just offering a solution for those who might not have the same constraints. cheers

Comment: Credit card expiry dates, roster start and end times, Bank Account BSB numbers, Hyphenated product codes. I'm less than 10% through a CRM and I've already found these 4 intuitive reasons for inline fields. Furthermore inline fields are supported by Bootstrap since `.form-group` and `.row` go hand in hand.

Comment: You forgot a scenario when you should select measure units. For example If you have a field for integer and then select for `Bytes/KBytes/MBytes/...`, you always want them to plase as close each to other as possible.

Comment: Works fine even if you don't want labels between, just leave the `class="input-group-addon"` empty and set `padding: 0' on the class

Comment: Nice answer. BTW, no need for custom CSS if you already have `style` attribute like in the answer

Answer (score 11):

To show **more than one** inputs inline **without** using "*form-inline*" class you can use the next code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="First input" />
    <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Second input" />
</div>
```

Then using CSS selectors:

```
/* To remove space between text inputs */
.input-group > .input-group-btn:empty {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Basically you have to insert an empty **span** tag with "*input-group-btn*" class between **input** tags.

If you want to see more examples of input groups and bootstrap-select groups take a look at this URL: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vkhusnulina/gze0Lcm0

Answer (score 9):

Create a input-group-glue class with this:

```css
.input-group-glue {
  width: 0;
  display: table-cell;
}

.input-group-glue + .form-control {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test1" />
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
  <span class="input-group-glue"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test2" />
</div>
```

Comment: This solved it for me, adding a glue class to my function in order to stick this together. I know 3.3.6 is outdated but our application still works with this.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to include a "Title" field within it that can be selected with the `<select>` HTML element, that too is possible

**PREVIEW**
[image]

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <select>
        <option>Mr.</option>
        <option>Mrs.</option>
        <option>Dr</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment, this is the only answer that uses bootstrap and an input group. Here's a jsfiddle using a slightly enhanced version of the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/1015/

Answer (score 7):

I have searched for this a few minutes and i couldn't find any working code.

But now i finaly did it ! Take a look:

```
<div class="input-group" id="unified-inputs">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal" />
</div>
```

And css

```
#unified-inputs.input-group { width: 100%; }
#unified-inputs.input-group input { width: 50% !important; }
#unified-inputs.input-group input:last-of-type { border-left: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Ln8d7zq/)

Comment: What if I have 3 inputs?

Comment: Updated for an infinite number of inputs http://jsfiddle.net/kgby6qfn/4/ You can now add how much inputs you need. 

But, this is an old solution. If you update to the latest bootstrap version, there is support for that: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs

Answer (score 2):

I was not content with any of the answers on this page, so I fiddled with this myself for a bit. I came up with the following

```js
angular.module('showcase', []).controller('Ctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.focusParent = function(event) {
    angular.element(event.target).parent().addClass('focus');
  };

  vm.blurParent = function(event) {
    angular.element(event.target).parent().removeClass('focus');
  };
});
```

```css
.input-merge .col-xs-2,
.input-merge .col-xs-4,
.input-merge .col-xs-6 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.input-merge div:first-child .form-control {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
.input-merge div:last-child .form-control {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.input-merge div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.input-merge div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) .form-control {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="showcase">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="container">
  <label class="control-label">Person</label>
  <div class="input-merge" ng-controller="Ctrl as showCase">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" name="initials" type="text" id="initials"
             ng-focus="showCase.focusParent($event)" ng-blur="showCase.blurParent($event)"
             ng-model="person.initials" placeholder="Initials" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" name="prefixes" type="text" id="prefixes"
             ng-focus="showCase.focusParent($event)" ng-blur="showCase.blurParent($event)"
             ng-model="persoon.prefixes" placeholder="Prefixes" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" name="surname" type="text" id="surname"
             ng-focus="showCase.focusParent($event)" ng-blur="showCase.blurParent($event)"
             ng-model="persoon.surname" placeholder="Surname" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

With this it is possible to set the width of the individual inputs to your liking. Also a minor issue with the above snippets was that the input looks incomplete when focussed or when it is not valid. I fixed this with some angular code, but you can just as easily do this with jQuery or native javascript or whatever.

The code adds the class .focus to the containing div's, so it can get a higher z-index then the others when the input is focussed.

Comment: how convert into normal function? because i don't understand angular... i cannot get the logic of your code

Comment: @AbuAyyub the angular code in answer has nothing to do with the styling. It's probably there just for completeness

Answer (score 2):

My solution requires no additional css and works with any combination of input-addon, input-btn and form-control.
It just uses pre-existing bootstrap classes

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form style="padding:10px; margin:10px" action="" class=" form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MinVal">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MaxVal">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This will be inline if there is space and wrap for smaller screens.

Full Example ( input-addon, input-btn and form-control. )

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/403/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form style="padding:10px; margin:10px" action="" class=" form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span></span>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span></span>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't even answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Combining two inputs, where the group take up all width (100%), and the size is not 50% - 50%, no additional css. I made it nicely by the following code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:100px;">
     <select class="form-control">
                     <option>Mr.</option>
                     <option>Mrs.</option>
                     <option>Dr</option>
                 </select>
    </span>
    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Type your name" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 4.1 I found a width solution by percentage:

The following shows an input-group with 4 Elements: 1 text an 3 selects - working well:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
 <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <div class="input-group-text">TEXT:</div>
 </div>
 <select name="name1" id="name1" size="1" style="width:4%;" class="form-control">
  <option value="">option</option>
  <!-- snip -->
 </select>    
 <select name="name2" id="name2" size="1" style="width:60%;" class="form-control">
  <option value="">option</option>
  <!-- snip -->
 </select>     
 <select name="name3" id="name3" size="1" style="width:25%;" class="form-control">
  <option value="">option</option>
  <!-- snip -->
 </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In react bootstrap the only thing you need is => d-flex

```
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="fullName">
              <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                value={fullName}
                onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="address">
              <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                value={address}
                onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </div>
```