# Bootstrap input-group with 2 textboxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a form with bootstrap for a web project, and I wanted to use the bootstrap input-groups on 2 textboxes, but they're not aligning as a group :/

I thought it would look like this :

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="first">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="second">
</div>
```

But, sadly, this doesn't work, and it's a bit hard to explain so here are some things i tried [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1bvqwsb/1/), but none of them is working.

I tried to add rows and to use columns but it didn't work. I don't even know if this is possible, but i think one of you may know some tricks to do this ?

Comment: Do you want them to just displayed as groups or is there a backend behavior associated with grouping them? If its just display, create a class with appropriate margins and apply it to the div.

Comment: how you want to align it?? you want some space between textbox?

Comment: I'd like to align them with no space, like if the buggon 'Go !' in the fiddle was a text input, d'you see what i mean ? :/ Sorry it's a bit tricky to describe

Comment: Look for this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/28331791/2629739

Comment: Ow ! I think that sould be alright ! Thanks a lot ! :D