# Why does this form break when placed inside a Bootstrap Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form and it breaks when placed inside a Bootstrap Jumbotron.

What needs to be done for this to work ok?

**Code**

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 well well-sm">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Quick Connect</h3>

        <form class="form" role="form" action="chat" method="post">
        <fieldset>

        <div class="input-group">
          <input name="nickname" type="text" placeholder="Enter a nickname, be creative!" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Enter Chat</button>
          </span>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
```

**Outside Jumbotron**

[image: OK]

**Inside Jumbotron**

[image: Not OK]

Thanks

Steve

**Edit:** Can someone also provide an example of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because jumbotron overrides btn-default to scale it up. You can try changing it to btn-small and see if that gives the desired result. If not you can just define a new css class and copy the normal style.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me in the right direction? I've tried using `btn-small` but this doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try input-group-addon? This is just off the cuff and I will do  little more digging to see because I'm interested in doing a quick connect inside a jumbotron.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20172807/3402347 found this elsewhere here. Doesn't look like input-group-addon is the right answer.