# Adding bootstrap class 'col-x-y' to MVC form breaks jumbotron

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div id="loginForm" class="col-md-8">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Please log in to continue.</h4>
                <hr/>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                </p>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
            }
        </div>
        <div id="messages" class="col-md-4">Messages go here ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the meat of this form is the auto-generated login code from creating a new MVC page. I have made the following changes:

- Changed `<section id="loginForm">` to `<div id=...>`
- Added the `col-md-4` div at the bottom
- Added `class="col-md-8"` to the `loginForm` div.

This last addition is where the problem seems to lie. See the following images:

[image: Without "col-md-8" on div]
[image: With "col-md-8"]

With the addition of `class="col-md-8"` on the `loginForm` div, the bottom of the `jumbotron` jumps to just after `<h4>Please log in ...</h4>`, but the `messages` div goes where I want it to.

If I remove the `col` class from `loginForm`, the form itself fits properly inside the jumbotron (but my other div goes below the form - not concerned about this currently).

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450881/why-does-this-form-break-when-placed-inside-a-bootstrap-jumbotron) regarding a similar problem, but changing the button style did not help.

EDIT:

There are two `css` files in use. I have not made any changes to either of these files.

The first is the `flatly` bootstrap theme, pulled directly from [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css).

The other file being used is `site.css`, defaulted from creation of the project:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

If I set the value of `loginForm`'s class to `col-x-12` (or remove it) the `jumbotron` renders properly, but the `messages` div drops below the form. Any lower value (11) causes the form to render in the same way - the border sits right below the `<h4>` field, and everything else is outside of the `jumbotron`.

What is causing this behavior on the `jumbotron`, and how can I fix it so that the `messages` div sits next to the form, and the `jumbotron` wraps the entire form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the loginform to col-md-12 to display the messages section below the form.  If you do that, does the jumbotron go where you need it to go?

If you do that and the jumbotron goes where you need it to go, try adding another container div inside the jumbotron including both the loginform and messages section. Maybe set the containing div to col-md-12 as well.

Comment: What I would like is for these columns to be side-by-side (i.e. messages next to the form). I changed the value to `col-md-12` and the jumbotron works again - similar to not having the class at all, but the messages screen falls below. Setting it to anything lower (11) breaks it. The css has been pulled directly from https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css. The only other css in effect is the default `site.css` file that comes with an mvc project. I have not made any changes to either css file.

Comment: Did you try adding another container div inside the jumbotron including both the loginform and messages section?  Maybe set the containing div to col-md-12 as well.

Comment: Always the simple things ... that worked! Thanks! Upvoted and accepted - can you please add that into the answer?

Comment: Glad it worked!  Will edit the answer.  Happy coding!